# Why no info in logcat?

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat

Why I have no logs by my tags? No errors or something like that.
Trying to get device info, using Kotlin.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var webview: WebView? = null
    var _MODEL = Build.MODEL
    var _MANUFACTURER = Build.MANUFACTURER
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("myTag", _MANUFACTURER)
        Log.d("myTag2", _MODEL)
        webview = findViewById<View>(R.id.browser) as WebView
        webview!!.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Log.i()` instead.

Comment: @broot yep, works like magic. thanks!